# Cannot find table elements to scrape pricing using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the pricing tables in the GCP site (https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing) for every region. I have tried a combination of BeautifulSoup and Selenium but finding the  tags always comes up blank. Have read similar questions but solutions end up with the same result. There must be something obvious I'm missing but can't put my finger on it. Appreciate any help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/pinzonpi/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

Comment: Try changing `lxml` to `html.parser`

Comment: Are you looking at any specific table?

Comment: It's probably because there is no `<table>` markup in the page... and all elements look like a table are `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Each table on that page is inside a separate iframe.
Browsers load the iframe content in a separate request. You'll have to do the same.
First you will have to get all the iframes list and then to scrape tables inside each iframe.
Something like this:

```py
iframes = soup.find_all('iframe')
for iframe in iframes:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(iframe.attrs['src'])
    iframe_soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
    table = soup.find('table')
    #continue scraping this table content
```